# Can you add a drop-down box for BoardColumn in TFS?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

In TFS, is it possible to add a drop-down box to the work item form that allows you to select/change the System.BoardColumn? Or is it only possible to change a board column via drag/drop on the board itself? This is in on premise TFS 2015

Use case: Sometimes we have an item open during a meeting to discuss it in depth. It would be easier to select a new column while the item is open for edit already than saving the item, then going back to the board to move it.

Comment: You can indeed just drag and drop the item in the other column.

Comment: Yep, that's what we normally do, but if we already have the item open anyways, I'd like to also have the option of moving it at the same time we're adding a comment or something, instead of having to open the item, update, then close, find it on the board, then move it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.BoardColumn` is a **read-only** field, you are not able to add a drop-down box for this field.

A workaround is mapping the State to the BoardColumn, and change the State field instead of BoardColumn field.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Just so we're on the same page, is this what you mean by mapping? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/customize-project-field-mapping-file?view=tfs-2015

Edit: Also, does this mean I need to ensure the values for State and BoardColumns match in the WIT def for the work item?

Comment: Perfect! That does exactly what I'm trying to do! Thanks so much